# matlab formatspec (number of digits to load from text file)

Tags: matlab

I have a text file with upto 16 digits (decimals) and Iam trying to load iut using matlab via the following snippet:

```
clc;
clear all;
formatSpec = '%16.16';

fileID = fopen('1_1_F','r');
f1 = fscanf(fileID,formatSpec);
```

So, I would like to load 16 digits + 16 decimals. However, the above code fails to load anything into my array f1. When I change my `formatSpec` to just `%f`, it works completely fine. Why is this? I am totally confused by this behavior.

Comment: What kind of error, how does it fail? Please add an example text file, I am unable to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It fails as in it does not show me anything for the variable f1. When I use `formatSpec = '%16.16';` it does not seem to read the text file at all - or it does and it seems to fail(?). Say I create a text file - with `68768.8762397828972890` and load it using the `formatSpec = '%16.16';` and then fscanf as shown in my code - does it load? for me, it does not. Variable f1 has nothing in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fscanf` does not allow specifying the number of digits, you have to use `textscan`. Here a format `%16.16f` does not match your data, the first number specifies the total number of digits, not those left of the `.`. You probably want:

```
x=textscan(fileID ,'%32.16f')
```

Comment: thank you vey much - works as expected now. Accepted your answer :)